# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (Xcode 14 + React Native)

Tags: xcode, react-native

Xcode builds debug for any simulator without any issue.
If target is a real device build fails with "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" issue.
Macbook M1
Rosetta installed and used for Xcode and terminal.
Pod reinstall and clean does not help.

Rosetta installed and used for Xcode and terminal.
Pod reinstall and clean does not help.
Certs are ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suggestion to check scripts under:
Xcode -> Target -> Build Phases and uncheck "Run script: For install builds only".
After unchecking such flags for all the scripts Xcode built debug version and installed on the device.
But it did not work because debug was not able to load js bundle because js bundle had not been generated as we unchecked flag to start it...
This gave a clue that the root of the issue are the scripts.
There were several scripts and checking and unchecking one by one I found a problem one - Bundle React Native code and images which starts
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
file.

It was found that this script was unable to work because of problems to find node app. I installed node with brew install node previously and node was in path. But by some reason it did not work for the script...
I removed this node and install nvm and node 14 version with

brew uninstall node

brew install nvm

nvm install 14

nvm use 14

Checked that "node -v" from command prompt starts exactly node 14.
Returned all the XCode project settings back.
Cleaned XCode project and started a new one build.
It created a new build and installed on the device without any issues